# Find sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|^p|b_n|$ converges only when $0<p\leq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Find sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|^p |b_n|$ converges only when $0<p\leq 1$  $(*)$

This is a smaller problem that orginated from a larger problem

> Suppose $f$ is a complex measurable function on $X$, $\mu$ is a positive measure on $X$, and $$\varphi(p)=\int_X|f|^pd\mu=||f||_p^p$$ Let $E=\{p: \varphi(p)<\infty\}$. Can $E$ consist of be any connected subset of $(0,\infty)$

Up til this point I have proven that $E$ can be of the form:

$$(a,b)$$

proving the forms:

$$(a,b],[a,b),[a,b]$$

Have been considerably more difficult. I reduced the problem of showing $E$ can have the form $(a,b]$ to solving $(*)$.

### How the reduction works

Take any complex measurable function $f$ and represent it as the sum $$f=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_n \chi_{A_n}$$ where $\alpha_i$ is a complex number and $\chi$ is the characteristic function.Then

$$\int_{X}|f|^{p}d\mu=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|\alpha_n|^{p}\mu(A_n)$$

let $a_n=\alpha_n$ and $b_n=\mu(A_n)$ we have the original question.

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If $p$ is constrained to be positive ($p>0$ no matter what):*

Take $(a_n)_n$, $(b_n)_n$ defined by $a_n = n$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n^2\ln^2 n}$.